# Upload to youtube using shell script

Tags: shell-script, scripting, youtube, upload

I've searched the youtube API but still not clear whether this is possible.
I have a shell script that uses FFMPEG to convert a video. After being converted I want to have the video automatically uploaded to a preauthorized youtube account.
Can any shell script gurus tell me if this is possible?

Comment: I'm not an API or curl expert, so I can't give you exact code for this, but see if this link helps you:
[This code sample calls the API's videos.insert method to upload a video to the channel associated with the request](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert#examples)

Answer (score 0):

Quick googling suggests https://github.com/tokland/youtube-upload/ and https://github.com/youtube/api-samples.